# Multi-Tenant Application Insights in MS Azure

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azure-application-insights

I am in the process of adding Microsofts Application Insights to our primary application. While this has gone smoothly, I also need to figure out a way to break down the metrics further by each client (SaaS product).

Page Views, Unique Users, Visits, etc. are listed for the site total. We would like the ability to view the page views for Client A without showing data from Client B.

I have found the TrackEvent option which would require building a compound event with not just client but also the page. I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to add extra data to the TrackPageView calls to alleviate some of this additional overhead as we are already tracking page views.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you may have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach custom properties and metrics to all telemetry types as described in the documentation: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-custom-events-metrics-api/#properties

Comment: I just got this working. Thanks for the great link. :)

Comment: It seems that the link above doesn't work anymore. I found this one instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties

Answer (score 1):

We also needed to use AI in a multi-tenant app, but we wanted to see which tenant data points correspond to and we also wanted to allow tenants to have their own AI configuration (in addition to the app-wide one).

The first one we've solved with a custom `ITelemetryInitializer` that sets the tenant name. And the second requirement we solved by instantiation `TelemetryConfiguration` and `TelemetryClient` ourselves (with the instrumentation key coming from the DB).

For the whole code that is an Orchard CMS module see: http://orchardazureappinsights.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Application Insights provides standard properties to track authenticated users id and their tenant. The property for tenant tracking is called `AccountId`.

More information could be found in the official documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.implementation.usercontext.accountid?view=azure-dotnet
- https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#setauthenticatedusercontext